# How do I expand a long number (ending in e+##) to show in expanded form?

Tags: python, numbers, variable-length

So, this may be a simple question but I'm having some trouble finding the answer anywhere.

Take for example I have a simple program where I want to divide a by b like so:

```
def main():
    a = 12345678900000000
    b = 1.25

    answer = (a / b)
    print(answer)
main()
```

This particular example would result in 9.87654312e+15. How do I get Python to ignore simplifying my number and just give me the whole number?

Thanks in advance, sorry if it's really basic, I wouldn't have asked if I could have found it through Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing the default `str()` conversion for floating point numbers at work. You can pick a different conversion by formatting the number explicitly.

The [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) can do this for you:

```
>>> n = 9.87654312e+15
>>> format(n, 'f')
'9876543120000000.000000'
```

See the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) documentation for more options. The `'f'` format is but one of several:

> Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.

The default precision resulting in the `.000000` six digits after the decimal point; you can alter this by using `.<precision>f` instead:

```
>>> format(n, '.1f')
'9876543120000000.0'
```

but take into account that decimals are rounded to fit the requested precision.

The `g` format switches between using exponents (`e`) and `f` notation, depending on the size of the number, but won't include decimals if the number is whole; you could use a very *large* precision with `'g'` to avoid printing decimals altogether:

```
>>> format(n, '.53g')
'9876543120000000'
```

To be explicit, `str(n)` is the same as `format(n, '.12g')`, `repr(n)` is `format(n, '.17g')`; both can use the exponent format when the exponent is larger than the precision.

Comment: `repr(n)` might also be an option

Comment: @JonClements: but that's another default format without much control.

Comment: That's why I said *might* - at least the precision doesn't require specifying `.1f` which might truncate in cases where more is required... depends how explicit the OP wishes to be... so that's why it *might* be okay :)

Comment: @JonClements: `repr()` is `format(n, '.17g')`, which happens to work *for this number*, but if the exponent were higher it'll still be shown.

Answer (score 1):

just be more specific about the floating point format

```
>>> print answer
9.87654312e+15
>>> print "%.20f" % answer
9876543120000000.00000000000000000000
```