# read long numbers from csv file

Tags: python

```
import csv
filename="test.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    a = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True,)]
#a[0]={'Base Number': '9.80623802581783E+022', 'sqlid': '324', 'Real value': '^0.47'}
```

The numbers in "Base Number" are being converted to E+ format, I tried the following

```
#a = [{k: int(v) for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True,)]
#a = [{k: float(v) for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True,)]
```

`os.popen('cat test.csv').read()`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cut","-d",",","-f","1", "test.csv"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
(x, y) = proc.communicate()
#print(x)
```

I want to get the number as is 
sample of test.csv

```
Base Number,sqlid,Real Value
55448712348468410374265,343,^0.47
55448712348468410375266,344,^0.32
98448712348468410374265,345,^0.32
```

Comment: post a testable fragment of your csv file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970451/how-do-i-expand-a-long-number-ending-in-e-to-show-in-expanded-form

Comment: When I run your first code snippet with the file shown in the question, `a[0]` is `{'Base Nuber': '55448712348468410374265',
 'sqlid': '343',
 'Real Value': '^0.47'}`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser in order to create the testable fragment I had to click "format as numeric" in "Libre office" then manually remove the commas and then I posted it here and that makes it work for the fragmented test file

Comment: Does that mean you have solved your problem?

Comment: Can't you open the actual csv in a text editor? And post the first few lines?